# Calculate resulting frequency from a given harmonic node, or multiple nodes, rounded to the nearest harmonic less than n

Tags: python, algorithm, math, signal-processing, physics

I'm working on a musical composition tool and I need to figure out what the resulting frequency would be if I touched (created a harmonic node) some arbitrary pitched string in one or more locations.

These positions need to be given as Midi pitches. So if I needed to create a harmonic with a fundamental of middle C and touch it at the 5th above (G) that would be written like this;

```py
Harmonic(60, 67) #3rd harmonic
```

which I'd expect to return 79, given:

```
def toFreq(m):
   return pow(2, (m-69)/12)
def toMidi(f):
   return 12 * math.log2( f/440 ) + 69
```

I have been able to implement this so far.

However, if I do:

```
Harmonic(60, 64) #5th harmonic
```

I get the wrong answer, this is because I want to 'round' the harmonic below -lets say- the 20th harmonic to reflect a real instrument. Which I have had some success getting to work by limiting the denominator of a `Fraction`. However this falls apart if I use a higher node from the same harmonic:

```
Harmonic(60, 69) # also the 5th harmonic, just a different node
```

The second issue I have, and I have had no success in getting this to work, is having multiple nodes like this.

```
Harmonic(60, [67, 65]) # where a 'C' string is touched at the 5th and 4th
# this is the 9th harmonic ( a compound major 2nd )
```

I was wondering if somebody could please help with the algorithm here? The actually classes and python stuff is no issue - this algorithm would go in the initaliser and set a member `self.sounding` -, and I'd happily have an answer is pseudo code! It also doesn't matter if the return is a midi pitch or frequency, it just needs to take a root pitch and one or more nodes (limited to two if that is easier).

Also, I hope I haven't over tagged this question!

Answer (score 2):

Does this work? My memory of the physics involved is pretty dim, but basically, we find the lowest pitch that is a common overtone of all of the given MIDI pitches.

```
import math


def freq_from_midi(m):
    return 440 * 2 ** ((m - 69) / 12)


def nearest_midi_from_freq(f):
    return round(12 * math.log2(f / 440) + 69)


def midi_overtones(m):
    f = freq_from_midi(m)
    return {nearest_midi_from_freq(h * f) for h in range(1, 21)}


def harmonic(*ms):
    return min(set.intersection(*(midi_overtones(m) for m in ms)))


print(harmonic(60, 67))
print(harmonic(60, 64))
print(harmonic(60, 69))
print(harmonic(60, 67, 65))
```

Comment: Thank you! I've posted a slightly modified version of this to take account of the fact the touched nodes aren't exact and will round to the nearest. That and fingers are infinity small!

Answer (score 1):

Submitting answer to own question.
Building off of David Eisenstat's answer taking account that an instrument will move the nodes slightly to find the lowest harmonic:

```
import math                                               
    
    
def freq_from_midi(m):    
    return 440 * 2 ** ((m - 69) / 12)    
    
    
def nearest_midi_from_freq(f):    
    return  round( 2 * (12 * math.log2(f / 440) + 69 )) / 2    
    
    
def midi_overtones(m):    
    f = freq_from_midi(m)    
    return { nearest_midi_from_freq(h * f) for h in range(1, 25)}    
    
    
def midi_overtones_flexible(m):    
    float_range = lambda start, stop, step: [start + step*r for r in range(0,int((stop - start)/step))]    
    
    freqs = (freq_from_midi(m + r) for r in float_range(-0.5, 0.5, 0.125) )    
    
    return { nearest_midi_from_freq(h * f) for f in freqs for h in range(1, 25)}    
    
    
def harmonic(base, *nodes):    
    overtones_of_base = midi_overtones(base)    
    overtones_of_nodes = [midi_overtones_flexible(m) for m in nodes]    
    r = set.intersection( overtones_of_base, *overtones_of_nodes )    
    return min(r)    
    
    
print(harmonic(60, 64, 66))  
print(harmonic(60, 65, 67))
```

Thank you David!